# data.table based function is altering the previous table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a time series data with two columns: 1) a POSIX date time column of 30 minute intervals and 2) a value for each interval, as shown below:

```
     read_date_time int_val
2013-01-15 15:00:00     2.3
2013-01-15 15:30:00     2.4
```

I've written a function that pivots the `data.table` so that there are 48 columns for each time interval for each row representing a day.

```
 read_date 00:00 00:30 01:00 01:30 ...
2013-01-15   1.3   1.4   1.2   1.5 ...
```

The function involved creating two new columns (`pure_date` and `interval`) which are used as IDs as part of the `reshape` function.  However I'm finding that the new columns are also added to the original table and the original `read_date_time` column is removed.

```
     int_val  pure_date interval
6.829986e-05 2013-08-31 00:00:00
6.887250e-05 2013-08-31 00:30:00
```

This causes numerous problems downstream as the original data set is reused in other functions.  I'm aware that I could probably bypass some of these problems using `data.frame` operations instead, however as I'm handling very large quantities of data and efficiency is key, really I need a `data.table` solution.

What am I doing wrong?

Code for replication....

```
require(data.table)
require(reshape)
require(stringr)

# Create time_array for example
set.seed(1L)                   ## for reproducibility
dt_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
time_seq <- seq.POSIXt(
         as.POSIXct("2012-01-01 00:00:00", format=dt_format),
         as.POSIXct("2013-12-31 00:00:00", format=dt_format),
         by = "30 mins")
values <- runif(NROW(time_seq),0,1)
combined_data_set <- data.table(read_date_time = time_seq, int_val = values)

> head(combined_data_set) # Format wanted

# Define Pivoting Function
pivot_data <- function(A) {
    con_data <- A
    con_data[,pure_date := as.Date(read_date_time)]
    con_data[,interval := str_sub(as.character(read_date_time),-8,-1)]
    con_data[,read_date_time := NULL]
    con_data <- data.table(read_date = as.character(con_data$pure_date), 
                           interval = con_data$interval,
                           int_val = con_data$int_val)
                           pivoted <- recast(con_data, read_date ~ interval, 
                           id.var = c("read_date","interval"))
    return(pivoted)
}

# Apply to data set
pivoted_output <- pivot_data(combined_data_set)

# Original data has been altered, what's happened!!!!!
> head(combined_data_set)
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, I'd realised it was a reference class issue soon after posting the question, but was struggling to find a solution that didnt sacrifice efficiency.

    con_data <- copy(A)

does the job nicely.

Cheers

Comment: I'll post a formal answer once I'm able to (my reputation doesnt permit at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

```
pivot_data <- function(A) {
    con_data <- copy(A)
    con_data[,pure_date := as.Date(read_date_time)]
    con_data[,interval := str_sub(as.character(read_date_time),-8,-1)]
    con_data[,read_date_time := NULL]
    con_data <- data.table(read_date = as.character(con_data$pure_date), 
                           interval = con_data$interval,
                           int_val = con_data$int_val)
                           pivoted <- recast(con_data, read_date ~ interval, 
                           id.var = c("read_date","interval"))
    return(pivoted)
}
```

As mentioned, just a school-boy error, copy(A) does the job....